# Is it Possible to change Google Docs viewer error message?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, google-docs

I am working on document viewer. is it possible to customize this `Error message: Whoops! there was a problem previewing this document` or how can I handle these types of error.

```html
<html>
            <head>
                <title>iframe Test</title>
                <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
            </head>
            <body>
                <div id="root">
       <iframe src="https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://www.peoplelikeus.org/piccies/codpaste/codpaste-teachingpack.pdf&embedded=true" style="width:600px; height:500px;" frameborder="0">                    Your browser does not support inline frames.
                    </iframe>
                </div>
            </body>
    
    </html>
```

I am following this:
https://gist.github.com/tzmartin/1cf85dc3d975f94cfddc04bc0dd399be

if you know other solution Please suggest me

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Going by the function name xssRequest it sounds like you're trying cross site request - which if that's right, you're not going to be able to read the contents of the iframe.  On the other hand, if the iframe's URL is on your domain you can access the body, but I've found thaenter code heret if I use a timeout to remove the iframe the callback works fine:

```
    $('#iframe').load(function () {
       if (typeof callback == 'function') {
          callback($('body', this.contentWindow.document).html());
       }
       setTimeout(function () {$('#iframe').remove();}, 50);
   });
```